# Bus to Bansko from Sofia

Tags: buses, bulgaria, sofia

I'm looking to go skiing next week, so I was wondering about the Bulgarian bus schedule from Sofia to Bansko. The only info I found was on Bansko (http://bansko.org/bansko_bus_schedule) website that says:

> From Central Bus Station Sofia:
>
> 7:30, 8.30, 9:45, 13:15 /except Sundays/, 14:00.
>
> From Bus Station Ovcha Kupel:
>
> 7:00, 9:20 /except Tuesday/, 10:30, 11:50 /except Sunday/, 13:05,
>   13:55, 14:30, 14:40, 15:10, 15:28 /except Tuesday/, 15:55, 16:30,
>   17:00, 17:30.

I'm not sure if this info is outdated. I definitely wouldn't want to arrive to Sofia and have to wait till tomorrow because all the buses for that day have already gone. Is there any official information about the bus schedule from Sofia to Bansko ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Central Bus Station has a website http://www.centralnaavtogara.bg/index.php

In the dropdown Дестинация select БАНСКО.

So the last bus from the Central Bus station seems to be leaving at 16:45

I have not found an authoritative website for Buses from Ovcha Kupel.

This site of the Bansko municipality lists slightly different times:

http://bansko.bg/en/component/content/article/10-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%9F%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95-%D0%9D%D0%90-%D0%90%D0%92%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%98-%D0%9E%D0%A2-%D0%98-%D0%94%D0%9E-%D0%90%D0%92%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%90-%D0%91%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%9E

Comment: 16:45, great! Thanks for the official site link. It definitely helps!